# How can I add menu items to the menubar in wxPython 4 after opening a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, wxpython

I have a basic menu bar of which the code is as follows:

```
# Add menubar
# Database menu
self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()
dbMenu = wx.Menu()
newDbItem = wx.Menu()
# New sub menu
dbNewItem = newDbItem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, 'New database...')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.newDbOnClick, dbNewItem)
# If there database loaded, show other menu items in 
# new submenu
if self.dbPath != None:
    # New table submenu item
    tableNewItem = newDbItem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, 'New table...')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.newTblOnClick, tableNewItem)
    # new row submenu item
    rowNewItem = newDbItem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, 'New row...')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.newRowOnClick, rowNewItem)
    # New column submenu item
    columnNewItem = newDbItem.Append(wx.ID_NEW, 'New column...')
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.newColOnClick, columnNewItem)
# Bind new submenu to db menu
dbMenu.AppendMenu(wx.ID_NEW, 'New', newDbItem)
# Open an already existing database file
openDbItem = dbMenu.Append(wx.ID_OPEN, 'Open...')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.openOnClick, openDbItem)
# Make a copy of the currently opened database
saveAsDbItem = dbMenu.Append(wx.ID_SAVEAS, 'Save as...')
self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.saveDbAs, saveAsDbItem)
# Exit the entire application
quitDbItem = dbMenu.Append(wx.ID_EXIT, 'Quit')
# Add the db menu to the menu bar
self.menubar.Append(dbMenu, '&Database')
```

Indeed, the options new table, new row and new column are not shown in the New submenu when the application starts, as I want. But, When I go to the menu and click the Open... option and select a file, so that the dbPath variable is not None anymore, but filled, the application doesn't show the extra menu items either.

I started looking on the web and I found several tips. One of them was refreshing the application, so my openOnClick event handler looks like this:

```
def openOnClick(self, e):
    dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, "Choose a database file", style=wx.FD_OPEN)
    if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        self.dbPath = dlg.GetPath()
        self.Update()
```

Although, this doesn't work at all. Another solution was using the Refresh method, so the last line of the previous example looks like this:

```
self.Refresh()
```

This didn't give me any improvement...

I don't really get an error message. The only thing that shows up each time is this:

> programma.py:37: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Call to deprecated item. Use Append  instead.
>     dbMenu.AppendMenu(wx.ID_NEW, 'New', newDbItem)

Can somebody help me find the right way to do this or maybe point out a mistake which I don't see?

Comment: Is the first code snippet executed again after `dbPath` became `!= None`?

Answer (score 0):

to add a Menu Item from an action (button click or menu event), the add menu item command must be inside the action.

Feel free to modify my example as you wish.

```
import wx

class AddMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddMenu, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.InitUI()

    def InitUI(self):

        self.menubar = wx.MenuBar()  

        self.fileMenu = wx.Menu()

        pnl = wx.Panel(self)

        pnl.SetBackgroundColour(wx.Colour(10, 15, 68))

        vbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        quitItem = wx.MenuItem(self.fileMenu, wx.ID_EXIT, '&Quit\tCtrl+Q', 'Quit application')
        quitItem.SetBitmap(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_QUIT))
        self.fileMenu.Append(quitItem) 

        addBtt = wx.Button(pnl, wx.ID_ANY, label='Add')

        vbox.Add(addBtt, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)


        pnl.SetSizer(vbox)


        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnQuit, quitItem)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.OnAdd, addBtt)

        self.menubar.Append(self.fileMenu, '&File')

        self.SetMenuBar(self.menubar) 

        self.SetSize((250, 130))
        self.SetTitle('AddMenu')
        self.Centre()

        self.CreateStatusBar()

    def OnQuit(self, e):
        self.Close()


    def OnAdd(self, e):
        newItem2 = wx.MenuItem(self.fileMenu, wx.ID_NEW, '&NewNew\tCtrl+M')
        newItem2.SetBitmap(wx.ArtProvider.GetBitmap(wx.ART_NEW))
        self.fileMenu.Append(newItem2)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    ex = AddMenu(None)
    ex.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```